# Is there a way to automatically delete messages older than a certain date with a certain label?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I have a ton of filters created that label e-mails in my inbox as they come in, so that I can easily discern between what groups they belong to with a quick glimpse. There are e-mails that get nested under, e.g. LABEL, and these are e-mails I read once and then archive, or sometimes just mark as read and archive (the subject line sometimes is enough to know what's going on inside it). However, after a week or so, the messages labelled LABEL are no longer of interest to me, and I delete them to prevent piling up of read and archived useless messages/e-mails.

What I want to know, is if there is some automatic way to get this latter part accomplished, since I now need to delete e-mails older than 7 days nested under LABEL manually. I know I can use filters to, in addition to adding a label to them as they come in, also delete or archive the e-mails. But that's not what I want; I want to be able to accomplish something like this:

1. E-mail comes in, filter acts upon it, and I see it labelled as LABEL as it drops into my inbox. This part is why a filter (as far as I could tell) is of no use for what I want, since I don't want the e-mail to skip the inbox;
2. I either read it or mark it as read, and then manually archive it;
3. It goes away from my inbox, but I can still access it through search, All Mail or LABEL;
4. **It gets deleted 7 days afterwards, automatically.**

Is there anyway to accomplish this? Either via the tools GMail has by default, or by some other means?

Comment: Not possible with just Gmail; filters only act on messages as they come in. You'll need some sort of 3rd party tool.

Comment: Ok, so it would fall under the "by some other means" category. Do you know anything in particular that could be of help here? Scripts, apps, tools?

Comment: A time-triggered script is the way to do it; if  the script posted by aparente001 didn't already exist, I'd write something like that (with the change I indicated under the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a script that is supposed to auto-purge older email messages: http://www.labnol.org/internet/gmail-auto-purge/27605/
I haven't tried it.

Comment: Tried this; it works. I only changed the deprecated method `ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers()` to  `ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()`. Also, I'd avoid using spaces in labels associated with this script [or at all] because Gmail changes spaces to hyphens in some places.

Comment: @Idisagree Should all instances of `getScript[something]` be replaced with `getProject[something]`? (example: `Session.getScriptTimeZone()`)

Comment: @JNat No, [that one is fine](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session). Google's naming decisions are what they are... The idea seems to be that triggers are grouped by a project (which may involve several scripts), while `Session.getScriptTimeZone()` is something that refers to the specific script being executed right now.

Comment: I used this with the changes @1999 left in the comments.